# How can I annotate facets that do not have data using ggplot2 facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have multivariate longitudinal samples that I am plotting in a large facet_grid, specifically using facet_grid so that when I don't have a certain time point for a certain sample it still keeps everything in a nicely ordered grid. I am trying to add some sort of indicator to empty facets to show that they don't have data (rather than just having no dots show up), because sometimes the empty facet is a result of not having collected that sample yet. What I have been able to get is a label that shows up in every facet that DOES have data, but I can't seem to figure out how to get a label that shows up in every facet that does NOT have data. It would be even better if I could add a red X through select facets, or some other indication of "No Data Available", rather than  a text label, if you have suggestions about that as well.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() + 
facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl)) + geom_text(x = 5, y = 20, label = "Blah")
```

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add rows for the missing combinations with a `full_join`. These new rows will have no data, so nothing will be plotted, but you can add an additional column with the message that `geom_text` will use:

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw())

mpg %>% 
  full_join(crossing(drv=unique(mpg$drv), cyl=unique(mpg$cyl))) %>% 
  mutate(empty=ifelse(is.na(model), "No data available", NA_character_),
         x=mean(range(displ, na.rm=TRUE)), 
         y=mean(range(cty, na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, cty)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl)) + 
    geom_text(aes(x, y, label=empty), colour="red", size=3)
```

[image]

For an "X", change the `empty` text to `"X"` and plot it with a large size. For example:

```
mpg %>% 
  full_join(crossing(drv=unique(mpg$drv), cyl=unique(mpg$cyl))) %>% 
  mutate(empty=ifelse(is.na(model), "X", NA_character_),
         x=mean(range(displ, na.rm=TRUE)), 
         y=mean(range(cty, na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, cty)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_text(aes(x, y, label=empty), colour="red", size=20) +
    facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl))
```

[image]

Or we could use `geom_segment`:

```
mpg %>% 
  full_join(crossing(drv=unique(mpg$drv), cyl=unique(mpg$cyl))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, cty)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_segment(data=. %>% filter(is.na(model)),
                 x=min(mpg$displ), xend=max(mpg$displ),
                 y=min(mpg$cty), yend=max(mpg$cty),
                 colour="red") +
    geom_segment(data=. %>% filter(is.na(model)),
                 x=min(mpg$displ), xend=max(mpg$displ),
                 y=max(mpg$cty), yend=min(mpg$cty),
                 colour="red") +
    facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl))
```

[image]

The above can be done with a single call to `geom_segment`, but it requires (AFAICT) a more complex data prep:

```
mpg %>% 
  full_join(crossing(drv=unique(mpg$drv), cyl=unique(mpg$cyl))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, cty)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_segment(data=. %>% 
                   filter(is.na(model)) %>% 
                   select(-displ, -cty) %>% 
                   crossing(
                     displ=range(mpg$displ),
                     cty=range(mpg$cty)
                   ),
                 aes(xend=rev(displ), yend=rev(cty)), colour="red") +
    facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl))
```

Comment: I really appreciate that you took the time to offer multiple ways of doing this. I was at first a bit confused as to why you chose the "model" variable for filtering, but in my own testing realized that any of the relevant variables work for the filtering purpose. I'm going to play around with this some more to figure out how I can give, for instance, differently colored X's for different situations. Thanks again for a great answer!

Comment: Any column (except the facet columns) will work for filtering if it always has data present in the original data. I used `model` because it's a short word that's quick to type. If there can be missing data in all columns of the original data frame, then you can just add a marker column to the original data frame and filter to keep only rows that have missing data for that column.